# DD-WRT: /tmp folder permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions, dd-wrt, chmod, tmpfs

After making a simple hello world OpenWRT package I installed it to the `/tmp` folder on the dd-wrt device. The program shows up in `ls /tmp` but when I try to execute it, it shows me `/tmp/helloworld: Permission denied`. First of all, I have to use the ram to store the package and program because my router doesn't support creating an additional flash memory partition (it's flash memory is 4MB). I tried `chmod +x /tmp/helloworld` and `chmod 777 /tmp/helloworld` but it returns the same error. What should I do to get it working? If relevant, I'm using DD-WRT v24-sp2.

EDIT:

Running `mount` shows me:

`rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp type ramfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=512K)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)`

Comment: Please provide the output of `mount` or the contents of `/proc/mounts`.

Comment: @DanielB the output of mount is `rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)`
`/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)`
`proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)`
`sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)`
`debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)`
`ramfs on /tmp type ramfs (rw,relatime)`
`none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=512K)`
`devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)`

Comment: Don't write important information in comments. Instead, update your question.

Comment: @DanielB is there something wrong with the ramfs mount?